# print equal operator

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to print an equal sign (`=`) in Python, using this code:

```
num= int(raw_input('Please enter a number:  '))
num2= int(raw_input('Please enter another number: '))
print '%s + %s' % (num, num2), = num + num2
```

I want the output to be:

```
5 + 10 = 15
```

However, I get the following error (using Python 2.7.8):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print '%s + %s' % (num, num2), = num + num2
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: And what exactly is stopping you?

Comment: thefourtheye's example below should be the answer, but in case you're curious, here's what you were trying to do using the approach above: `print '%s + %s = %s' % (num, num2, num + num2)`

Comment: Or perhaps, `print '%s + %s' % (num, num2), '= %s' %(num+num2)`.

Comment: It works both ways. I was confused about the format. Thanks both of you.

Comment: I've edited your question.  If you ask questions using a format similar to this one, you'll avoid downvotes in the future.

Comment: How would you convert the int to float on the final result. `print '%s / %s' % (num, num2), '= %s' %f(num/num2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a format string and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function, like this

```
print '{} + {} = {}'.format(num, num2, num + num2)
```

The parameters to `str.format` will be replaced in the respective `{}`. Make sure that you match the number of parameters with the number of `{}`.